# Is there a way to do SpiderOak setup from an Ubuntu 12.04 server command line without a GUI?

Tags: backup, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox, headless

We're experimenting with SpiderOak for a few server backup tasks. (We preferred to avoid dropbox if possible, though that may end up as a fallback.) We've installed the client on our local Mac and Windows stations, so we'll have easy access to the backups once they exist, but the tough part seems to be on the server itself.

We successfully installed the software using SpiderOak's apt-get repository for that purpose. However, running the client from the command line results in this message:

**SpiderOak: cannot connect to X server**

... and running it with the *--headless* flag, per their documentation, leads to another error:

**Command line arguments not allowed during New User Setup**

So my question in short form: Am I just out of luck without a GUI, or is there a CLI-only method of getting around this and proceeding with setup of my SpiderOak install?

Comment: A quick google search for 'spideroak cli setup' led me to [this page](https://spideroak.com/faq/questions/1017/how_do_i_set_up_a_new_user_from_the_commandline/).

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried three or four similar terms without success -- looks like you found the right one. I appreciate it. If you're willing to make that an answer, I'll be happy to mark the issue as solved under your name.